# Refresh button after changing style color

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, win-universal-app

So, I have a button template in a resource dictionary. Its colour property in its normal VisualState binds to a DependencyProperty defined in the MainPage C# code. Notice that MainControl is the MainPage name.
Here's the Button template:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ellipse.(Shape.Fill)" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=ButtonColor}">
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Target="ellipse.(Shape.Stroke)" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            [Other Visual States...]
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's the MainPage XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="Volumio.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Volumio"
Name="MainControl">
<Grid Background="#FF525C66">
    <Button x:Name="toggle" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="132" Margin="40,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
</Grid>
```

And here is where I define the Property:

```
public static DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush),
        typeof(Page), PropertyMetadata.Create(NormalColor));

    public SolidColorBrush ButtonColor
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

The problem is: whenever I set the ButtonColour property to a different colour, the Button doesn't change its colour automatically, instead I have to change VisualState and then return to normal to make it refresh and change colour. I change the property in async voids. Does this matter?

Where is the problem? Do I have to refresh it manually from the code?

It may be obvious but I'm new to XAML programming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Setter`s under a `VisualState` will only applied once when a `VisualState` is used as the current state. And when a `Setter` is applied, it obtains the value from its `Value` property and set to the target element and property specified in its `Target` property.

So it won't set your `Binding` to the `Fill` property of your `ellipse` and you button won't change its color unless the button's `VisualState` become `Normal` again.

If you want your button change color automatically, you can remove the `<Setter Target="ellipse.(Shape.Fill)" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=ButtonColor}"></Setter>` in `VisualState.Setters` and use the `Binding` in `Ellipse` like:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="{Binding ElementName=MainControl, Path=ButtonColor}" />
```

Or to reuse this `Style`, we can bind `Fill` property to `Button`'s `Background` property like this:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
```

and in MainPage XAML using:

```
 <Button x:Name="toggle"
    Width="132"
    Height="132"
    Margin="40,146,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Background="{Binding ElementName=MainControl,
                         Path=ButtonColor}"
    Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: Yes Jay Zuo, it worked perfectly. I removed the VisualStates as I'm going to control them through C#. Thanks a lot :-)